# I want the bash script to echo only if I execute and not echo if executed by a cron job

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal

I want to echo to the terminal if the script is being executed by me, in the flesh or I want to echo to a log file if it is being done via a cron job.

Ubuntu 16.04

example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ***** ]; then
   echo "You executed this script just now !";
else
   echo "You were executed by the server cron at ${date}" >> example.log
fi
```

I rewrote the above because I thought it would be a simpler way to explain it. It's a more direct and cleaner example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    echo "executed from terminal"
elif [[ $(< /proc/$PPID/comm) == cron* ]]; then
    echo "executed by cron"
else
    echo "executed outside of a terminal"
fi
```

Comment: Or, `if tty -s`.

Comment: I rewrote my question because I feel your statement can fit my somehow.

Comment: Check my new full featured snippet ;)

Comment: This will work. Now I can direct my messages for actions correctly. Thank you, Gilles.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can set an environment variable in your crontab file and then let the script check for the variable. I.e. in you crontab add CRON=yes

in your script

if [[ "$CRON" = "yes" ]]; then

or simply check if $CRON is defined [[ -z "$CRON" ]]

Answer (score -1):

Super easy way: just create a file before.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/FOO && /your_script/

[ -f /tmp/FOO ] && echo "Executed by crontab"; rm /tmp/FOO || echo "I'm physically executing"
```